# What is the difference between using as_str on a function's output or on a variable?

Tags: rust

I am writing a Rust function to get configuration from a file, this is the function:

```
pub fn getConfig(key: &str) -> String {
    let mut settings = config::Config::default();
    settings.merge(config::File::with_name("settings")).unwrap()
        .merge(config::Environment::with_prefix("APP")).unwrap();
    let hashConfig = settings.try_into::<HashMap<String, String>>().unwrap();
    let conn = hashConfig.get(key).unwrap();
    let std =String::from(conn);
    return std;
}
```

When I use this function like this:

```
fn main() {
    let config = getConfig("key");
    let conf = config.as_str();
    print!("{}",config)
}
```

it works fine. But when I use the function like this:

```
fn main() {
    let config = getConfig("key").as_str();
    print!("{}",config)
}
```

It shows an error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:30:18
   |
30 |     let config = getConfig("key").as_str();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                  |
   |                  creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
31 |     print!("{}",config)
   |                 ------ borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

What is the difference? Why should I write to a variable first? why should not use `as_str` directly after the function?

Comment: `let config = getConfig("key")` keeps the value alive. `let conf = config.as_str()` is valid because the lifetime of `config` can be proved to outlive `conf`. But if you Inline its value, calling `getConfig("key")` returns a temporary that only lives until the end of the statement. If allowed, `conf` would have a dangling pointer, because it outlives the data it relies on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetConfig` returns an ***owned*** value which then you take a ref to with `as_ref`. But the problem is that nothing is really owning it, so the reference gets invalidated. You want to have a variable to ***own*** the value, and later you can get the reference to that value which is already owned.